# Blinking cells within selection

Tags: excel, vba, macros

I'm using a code which makes certain cells blink. I've modified the code to make only selected cells blink. The problem is that macro doesn't "stay" with the cell after I change selection.
For example: If I select cell B6 and run macro - it starts blinking, then I select cell B7 and B6 stops blinking but B7 starts, without even running macro.
How could I fix that?

Current code:

```
Option Explicit
 Dim NextBlink As Double

 Sub StartBlinking()

    If Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
        Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    Else
        Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If
    NextBlink = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 0.6)
    Application.OnTime NextBlink, "StartBlinking", , True

End Sub
```

Comment: The code only blink the selected cell.  Once the cell is not selected, it stop blinking.

Comment: Any solution to that?

Comment: You'd have to amend it to keep an array of the cells you had selected previously and then identify anything selected again which was already in that array. I'm not saying it would be easy though...

Comment: Sounds complicated... I'll try though.     Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit
Dim NextBlink As Double
Dim blinkingcells As Range
Sub StartBlink() 'call this make current cell start blinking
    If blinkingcells Is Nothing Then
        'start blinking
        Set blinkingcells = Selection
        Call Blinking
    Else
        'blinking already, just add more blinkingcells
        Set blinkingcells = Union(blinkingcells, Selection)
    End If
End Sub

Sub Blinking()
'make cells in global range "blinkingcell" blink
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In blinkingcells
        If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
           cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        Else
           cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    Next
    NextBlink = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 0.6)
    Application.OnTime NextBlink, "Blinking", , True
End Sub
```